# Create a local only network between Mac OS X computer and other PC's

Tags: networking, macos, ethernet, dhcp, local

I want to create a local network between my Mac OS X computer and some other computers I have. I want to connect these via an ethernet connection, routed via a switch.

Unfortunately as I am on a corporate network I cannot simply share my internet connection from wifi using the regular Mac OS X "share my internet connection" option in system settings. *This does **not** work!*

I think what I need to do is configure my Mac OS X computer to run  a dhcp server on the ethernet interface so that other computers can connect and disconnect arbitrarily. However this network must be a local only network as viewed from the corporate network side! (It should essentially be invisible to the corporate hardware.)

I intend to use this to ssh into a backup server and copy files using rsync to and from a (private) backup server.

PS: I have permission to do this etc etc, the network is just set up in a secure way which means anyone sharing an internet connection is removed from the network automatically.

Comment: In effect, you want to use your Mac as a router, and host a small LAN. Since the Mac is on wifi, it must also act as a wifi bridge. If your network allows it, setting up a bridge and a router is probably the most reliable way, especially if your network is applying NAC rules to wifi connectivity. A DHCP server will not address the problem, because right now, you haven't been able to configure the Mac as a gateway router, due to the NAC restrictions, so there is no way for traffic going in the ethernet to go out the wifi (or vice versa, though you mention that it shouldn't).

Comment: Hi Frank to clarify I do NOT want to share the internet connection, I want to setup an isolated local network

Comment: then it sounds like you need only statically assign IPs for the small number of hosts, and plug everything in. you could set up a DHCP server, but you would need to be careful to restrict it to the ethernet interface. Other than that, I am unclear what your question is then, or why you bring up internet connection sharing.

Comment: I mentioned it because I assume it would be the default thing people suggest - but for the reasons described above it will not work